# How to prevent jquery-ui selectmenu to become slower when updating selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use a `jquery-ui` `selectmenu` and I need to update the selected option from code.
To do that i use this:

```
setOption (menuId, option) {
    let index = $(`${menuId} option[value="${option}"]`).index();
    $(menuId)[0].selectedIndex = index;
    $(menuId).selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

The problem is that after a while it gets slower and slower.

The reason seems to be that internally everytime refresh is called `jquery-ui` creates new `div-wrappers` and adds them to its bindings, not removing the old ones.

Is there a better way to update the `selectmenu` to prevent this?